# How to set a static alarm to go off at a set time every day?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using this to set a alarm to go off every 24 for hours from the time the application was opened.

Instead of 24 hours from the time it was opened. i want to set a static time like at 8:00am every morning according to device the alarm goes off.

Here is what i have so far.

```
 String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(alarm);
                    Intent intent = new Intent("NEW_ITEM");
                    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
                     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                     calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

Comment: If you cant see what the question is dont answer it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` as your second argument, just calculate 8am of the next day and pass that in.

Comment: How would i go about calculating 8am the next dau? Especially if the time is different on different devices.

Comment: How is time different on different devices?! What does that mean? Just create a `Calendar` object, use `setTimeInMillis`, and then start shifting things around. You can also handle the timezone with the calendar. (I should note that Jeff Sharkey deprecated Calendar since it's quite heavyweight, but for your purposes, it's the easiest to use.)

Comment: Look at the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html . Also, this class is coming from J2SE, so there are lots of non-Android-specific tutorials and samples out there.

Comment: So you would get a instance of calendar...then what.. Im kind of confused on how it would tie in with AlarmManager

Comment: The calendar converts the currentTimeMillis() into a full date with hours, minutes, seconds, etc. Then you modify those hours to 8am of the next day. Then you convert it back to a long and pass that into the AlarmManager.